# Open jump menu selection in new window

Tags: views, 7

I have a views jump-menu of PDFs. I'd like the PDF to open in a new window when the user clicks the "go" button on the view.

I've tried using javascript to set the form's `target` attribute to `_blank`. It is showing in the markup, but it has no effect on the behavior of the form submission.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I've found to do this so far is to alter the ctools jumpMenu behaviour with the following JS. This is probably a lot more code than I need, but it seems to do the job. Better answers are appreciated.

**JS**

```
// place this outside your .ready() function
Drupal.behaviors.CToolsJumpMenu = {
   attach: function(context) {
     $('.ctools-jump-menu-hide:not(.ctools-jump-menu-processed)')
       .addClass('ctools-jump-menu-processed')
       .hide();

     $('.ctools-jump-menu-change:not(.ctools-jump-menu-processed)')
       .addClass('ctools-jump-menu-processed')
       .change(function() {
         var loc = $(this).val();
         if (loc) {
           location.href = loc;
         }
         return false;
       });

     $('.ctools-jump-menu-button:not(.ctools-jump-menu-processed)')
       .addClass('ctools-jump-menu-processed')
       .click(function() {
         // Instead of submitting the form, just perform the redirect.

         // Find our sibling value.
         var $select = $(this).parents('form').find('.ctools-jump-menu-select');
         var loc = $select.val();
         if (loc) {
          // console.log(loc.slice(loc.indexOf('::') +2) );
           // location.href = loc.slice(loc.indexOf('::') +2);
           window.open(loc));
         }
         return false;
       });
   }
 }
```

[Source](http://alvinalexander.com/drupal-code-examples/drupal-7-ctools-project/js/jump-menu.js.shtml)